# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier en un setTimeout( )

Tags: javascript

Realizo una carga dinámica del siguiente archivo:

```
full.js

window.APP = {
  SKIN: 'FSKIN',
  Run: function( ) {
    var layout = {

    };

    console.log( 'Lanzando <full>' );
    debugger;
    setTimeout( window.SPINNER.stop( ), 2000 );
  }
}
```

Al decir *dinámica*, me refiero a que lo cargo mediante AJAX, **no** con

```
<script src="full.js"></script>
```

Al cargar la página en el navegador, funciona bien. El resto del codigo hace lo que tiene que hacer, el archivo es cargado, y se llama a la funcion `APP.Run( )`.

Al llegar a `debugger;`, todo es correcto. Si en la consola tecleo

> typeof( SPINNER.stop )

me responde

```
"function"
```

Pero si continuo a partir de ahí, o directamente quito `debugger`, me muestra el error indicado

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

seguido de un código `VM`, y no me muestra el código fuente implicado. No hay pila de llamadas ni nada por donde buscar.

¿ Porqué me muestra ese error ?

**EDITO**

El `SPINNER` es una pequeña librería esterna: http://spin.js.org/

Y lo creo como

```
window.SPINNER = new Spinner( CONFIG.SYSTEM.SPINNER ).spin( document.body );
```

El `SPINNER` en sí funciona bien.

Por si sirve de algo, la *pila* de llamadas seria:

```
ready( function( ) {
  ajax( URL, function( res ) {
    app = new Function( res );
    app( );
    APP.Run( );
  } );
} );
```

No uso `jquery`, pero creo que se entiende.

**EDITO 2**

Esto es una modificación que he realizado del archivo `full.js`:

```
window.APP = {
  SKIN: 'FSKIN',
  Run: function( ) {
    setTimeout( window.SPINNER.stop.call( window.SPINNER ), 2000 );
  }
}
```

El resultado es el mismo, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Después, he intentado esto:

```
window.APP = {
  SKIN: 'FSKIN',
  Run: function( ) {
    setTimeout( function( ) { window.SPINNER.stop( ); }, 2000 );
  }
}
```

**¡ Ahora si !**
No muestra ningún error, y todo funciona correctamente.

Entiendo que, al hacer `setInterval( )`, estoy creando un *evento* y colocándolo en la cola de eventos del sistema. Para prevenir posibles problemas, utilizo los nombres *completamente cualificados* de la variable y el método que uso: `window.SPINNER.stop( )`.

La pregunta original sigue en pie:

¿ Porqué ocurre esto ? ¿ Cuál es la diferencia entre realizar la llamada al método `SPINNER.stop( )` dentro o fuera de una función anónima ?

**EDITO 3**

Lo que he probado hasta ahora:

```
setTimeout( window.SPINNER.stop( ), 1000 );

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

**Grave** error por mi parte. Los paréntesis, como bien indican OscarGarcia y Guz.

```
setTimeout( window.SPINNER.stop, 1000 );
```

**No** hay error, pero **no funciona**. El `SPINNER` sigue girando.

```
setTimeout( function( ) { window.SPINNER.stop( ); }, 1000 );
```

**Si** funciona. No hay error. Todo OK.

Comment: ¿Cómo haces la carga "dinámica"? ¿Has comprobado que no se acceda a dicha referencia antes de cargarla "dinámicamente"? ¿Podrías tratar de preparar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sobre el que trabajar?

Comment: @OscarGarcia La carga dinámica funciona bien. Se muestra el mensaje `Lanzando <full>`. El ejemplo dependería de la librería `webix`, así que sería díficil :-(

Comment: No es necesario que hagas una reproducción completa, sólo de lo mínimo que genere ese mismo problema. ¿Has comprobado qué vale `window.SPINNER` después del `Lanzando <full>`? ¿Has probado a poner `'window.SPINNER.stop( )'` entre comillas o `window.SPINNER.stop` sin los paréntesis? PD: Si me confirmas que eso arregla tu problema abro una respuesta explicándote el motivo del error.

Comment: @OscarGarcia: `window.SPINNER` es un `Object`. Tanto si lo pongo entre comillas, como si omito los paréntesis, **no** da error, pero **no detiene el spinner**. He editado la pregunta, con la única forma de que funcione sin errores que he encontrado.

Comment: Creo que OscarGarcía se refiere a la función `stop` de `SPINNER` De hecho, si lo dejas con paréntesis solo se va a ejecutar una vez ya que `setTimeout` acepta **una función** como primer parámetro y la ejecución de una función **no devuelve nada**, por ende, el **el timeout no cumplirá su cometido**.

Comment: Exacto, sólo se ejecutará en el momento de hacer la llamada.. esa era mi teoría. Lo de la función anónima debiste decirlo antes ya que el código que usas no lo es. PD: acabo de fijarme que editaste la pregunta y lo añadiste. En cuanto pueda te explico la diferencia en una respuesta

Comment: @OscarGarcia Cierto, teneis razón, los jodidos paréntesis que se colaron. Pero, curiosamente, aunque los elimine, **no da error**, pero **no funciona**. Lo de colocar la llamada en una función anónima lo he hecho hace poco, mucho después de publicar la pregunta. Aún así, porque **solo** funciona con una función anónima ?

Comment: No tiene que ver nada que se haga o no mediante una función anónima/closure/IIFE porque se está usando el scope `window` y éste **siempre está disponible**, por eso se le llaman *variables globales*. De hecho, si ejecutas: `window.nombre = function () { alert('Trauma'); }; setInterval(nombre, 3000);` verás que funciona correctamente. Si haces una IIFE dentro del callback de `setTimeout` funcionará igualmente.

Comment: @Guz, he editado con lo que ha pasado, mas o menos. Sigo sin entenderlo porque, como bien dices, uso el nombre completo: `window.SPINNER.stop`.

Comment: El error se debe a que dentro del método `stop` se hace referencia a `this`, con la idea que se refiera al objeto `Spinner`, pero al colocar el método directamente como callback lo que pasará es que `this` referenciará a `window` en lugar de a `Spinner`. Es por eso que si en lugar de pasar directamente el método `stop` lo pones dentro de una función, todo funcionará correctamente. De igual modo funcionará si haces: `setInterval(spinner.stop.bind(spinner), 3000);`. Ten cuidado con `this` en JavaScript, éste siempre referenciará al `ámbito/scope actual`.

Comment: PD: Puedes ver el método `stop` en [su repo](https://github.com/fgnass/spin.js/blob/master/spin.js#L230) en GitHub.

Comment: @Guz ok. Estoy empezando con JS; ya sabia algo de eso, por eso usaba el nombre completo, pero no me esperaba ese comportamiento tan *curioso*. Monta una respuesta solo con esa explicación, que la acepte.

Comment: Ya está la explicación en mi respuesta, @Trauma. Como ves JavaScript es un poco exquisito para algunos temas ;)

Comment: Bueno, nada.. un rato de redacción perdido.. :/ voy a dar el +1 que se lo merece xD

Comment: @OscarGarcia se te adelantó. Esto es la ley del Viejo Oeste. El más rápido, gana ;-) Ya haré mas preguntas, estoy empezando con esto del JavaScript, así que alguna saldra **seguro**.

Comment: Lo siento @OscarGarcia :(. Trauma me gustan preguntas así que tratan del core del lenguaje, siempre es bueno repasar esos conceptos y si así ayudas, mucho mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Nota:** No debes ejecutar una función si la pasas como callback De hecho, si lo dejas con paréntesis (ejecución) solo se va a ejecutar una vez ya que `setTimeout` acepta una función como primer parámetro y la ejecución de una función no devuelve nada (`undefined`); por ende, el el timeout no cumplirá su cometido.

#### Problema

El error es referente a ámbitos de alcance o `scopes`. Estás pasando la referencia de la función `stop` como callback **sin establecer el scope** al que debe referenciar `stop`.

Cuando haces:

```
window.setInterval(SPINNER.stop, 3000);
```

El ámbito de alcance de `stop` será el global, es decir `window`. ¿Por qué? La razón es sencilla:

> En JavaScript el ámbito de `this` siempre será en donde se ejecute.

Por ende, ya que el ámbito de `setTimeout` es `window`, entonces el ámbito de `stop` será también `window`.

#### Solución

La solución es sencilla, puedes hacerlo de dos formas:

- Pasando un closure como callback a `setInterval` y ejecutando en ella `stop`.

  ```
  setInterval(function () { SPINNER.stop(); }, 3000);
  ```
- Estableciendo el ámbito del método `stop` por medio de [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind).

  ```
  setInterval(SPINNER.stop.bind(SPINNER), 3000);
  ```

Al usar `bind` se creará una nueva función reemplazando el ámbito por el pasado por parámetro.

---

Elijas la forma que elijas, funcionará correctamente.